# setState not working inside AsyncStorage in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

setState not working inside AsyncStorage in React Native.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {userId: ''};
}

componentDidMount() {

    AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_ID', (err, result) => {
        if (!err && result != null) {
            this.setState({
                userId: result
            });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                userId: null
            });
        }
    });

    alert(this.state.userId);
    let userId = this.state.userId;

    fetch('http://localhost/JsonApi/myprofile.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            userId: userId,
        }),
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({userDetails: responseJson});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });

}
```

Setting the `userId` value using `setState` and alert returns no value at all. Tried other solutions from Stackoverflow but not as per my expectation.

Note: Code updated. After getting userId from AsyncStorage, it will be passed to fetch. Here, userId value is missing.

Comment: Are you sure, the callback is triggered. Also, setState changes may not be immediately reflected. I see that you are trying to alert the value later. It may not help.

Comment: sometime AsyncStorage take time to execute and it may be possible that your state is called before AsyncStorage execute. So for debugging console.warn("check state,"this.state.userId) inside the render method. (because render call everytime when state is change . )try this and let me know

Comment: @anilsidhu Let me check that. I am thinking the same. But, not found a way to rectify it.

Comment: @anilsidhu Yes. Its working. But the thing is that, I want to sent this userId via a fetch. At the time of fetching it's not getting this values. And POST sent with null value. How can I solve that ..?

Comment: i am making answer for this for better code format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2 ways to do this. One is Simple but other is correct way according to react recommendation**

One is here- pass value to state directly.

```
 .then((responseJson) => {
           // this.setState({userDetails: responseJson});
      this.state.userDetails=responseJson;
     this.setState({});   //for update render
        })
```

Second Way is here

in the render function Check state Value like this .if UserDetails state is null it will be not give you error whenever userDetails state get data render execute again and provide perfect result.

```
          render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.userDetails ?
          this.state.userDetails.map((data, index) =>
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{data.userName}</td>
              <td>{data.userEmail}</td>
            </tr>
          )
          : null
        }
 </div>)}
```

**Let me know gain. if facing issue**

Comment: Hi, your solution will work. but, I updated the code, have you seen that. I want to pass that value to fetch. There it will not work.

Comment: async componentDidMount()
{
await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_ID', (err, result) => ....................
}

try this one .  now your code will wait for AsyncStorage and then execute next code

Comment: Yes. it works. Thanks. The solution was this simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wrote so much code.

#### First way

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("USER_ID").then((value) => {
       console.log("userId in async = " + value);
       this.setState({
            userId: value
     });
});
```

- You don't need to check `error` & `result` both because if that is null, you are setting userId null in state. so you can directly set `value` to state `userId`.
- Also set a log to see what is output of your async storage userId.
- Please also verify that you are setting value in "USER_ID" somewhere.

#### Second way

There can **different ways** also like using `async` method.

```
const getUserId = async () => {
  try {
    const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_ID') || 'none';
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
  }
  return userId;
}
```

and you can use

```
this.setState ({
  userId : getUserId()
});
```

**I don't like this way because I need to create another method with `async` & `await` keywords.**

#### I use the first way so.

**Update**

Do your work related to userId inside `getIten();`, because you alert userId immediately after calling `AsyncStorage`. And `AsyncStorage` returns value after you call `alert`.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("USER_ID").then((value) => {
       console.log("userId in async = " + value);
       this.setState({
            userId: value
     });
       alert(this.state.userId); // move this line here
});

// removed from here
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use the promise based API. The official API supports callbacks as well. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#getitem.

Comment: @Khemraj Tied the first way before. it's not working. State is called before AsyncStorage execute.

Comment: What mean not working? You can provide what are you getting, is there any error in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to alert after updating state. You will get callback once state is updated.

```
this.setState({
                userId: result
            },function(){
        console.log("userId in async = ", this.state.userId);
        alert(this.state.userId);
});
```

Comment: Alerting after updating will work. I want to get the value after AsyncStorage. State is called before AsyncStorage execute. That is the issue I want to overcome.

Comment: Show your full code. Because it clearly shows setState `userId: result` will call after `AsyncStorage` callback. and `AsyncStorage` will be called into Async thread. So looks like from some other code your state is updating.