# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined react redux when updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am updating a post then when I click update I got this error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined..

here's my reducers the payload is

```
action.payload: {id: 1, title: "test", body: "update"}

case UPDATE_POST:

    const updatedItems = state.items.map(item => {
        if(item.id === action.payload.id){
            return { ...item, ...action.payload }
        }
        return item
    })
    return updatedItems
```

Here's my post component render

```
const postItems = this.props.posts.map(post => (
     <div key={post.id} className="row">
         <div className="container">
             <h3>{post.title}</h3>
              <p>{post.body}</p>
              <button
                  onClick={() =>this.editPost(post)}
                  className="btn btn-primary">
                  Edit
              </button>&nbsp;
              <button
                  onClick={() =>this.deletePost(post.id)}
                  className="btn btn-danger">
                  Delete
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>  
  ))
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of the `items` array?

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the array using `state.items` it means array is part of object and the key is items. So at the end you need to return an object with updated items but you are returning an array from reducer.

Write it like this:

```
case UPDATE_POST:

    const updatedItems = state.items.map(item => {
        if(item.id === action.payload.id){
            return { ...item, ...action.payload }
        }
        return item
    })

    return {...state, items: updatedItems }
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the data is coming or not in  Props and then use it. and also debug it with console in render for check that data is coming or not. if data is coming then it should work.If still facing issue let me know
your issue is similar as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779469/setstate-not-working-inside-asyncstorage-in-react-native/51781016#51781016)

```
this.props.posts ?
const postItems = this.props.posts.map(post => (
     <div key={post.id} className="row">
         <div className="container">
             <h3>{post.title}</h3>
              <p>{post.body}</p>
              <button
                  onClick={() =>this.editPost(post)}
                  className="btn btn-primary">
                  Edit
              </button>&nbsp;
              <button
                  onClick={() =>this.deletePost(post.id)}
                  className="btn btn-danger">
                  Delete
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>  
  ))
: null
```